# Does this Bootstrap responsive layout need two separate grids?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I want my login page to look like this on xs/sm viewports:

```
label1     
[input1]      

label2
[input2]
```

and this for md/lg viewports:

```
label1       label2
[input1]     [input2]
```

however my solution requires a separate grid for each

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- small screens -->
      <div class="visible-xs visible-sm">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="username">username</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input type="text" name="username" />
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="password">password</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input type="text" name="password" />
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>


      <!-- large screens -->
      <div class="visible-md visible-lg">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label for="username">username</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-1"></div>

                  <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label for="password">password</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-7"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" name="username" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-1"></div>

                  <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" name="password" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-7"></div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Can one grid accomplish this?  Also how and why would I use form-group in this layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this code to get rid of the problem

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- For all screens -->
      <div class="visible-lg visible-md visible-xs visible-sm">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label for="username">username</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" name="username" />
              </div>
            </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" name="Password" />
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And `.form-group` is needed for optimum spacing..

Comment: This does work but places the inputs much too far apart on larger screens.  And I am trying to avoid this kind of complicated grid code.